# can JavaDB use SQL statements?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, javadb

I need to make a project in java where I am going to create a database, but my problem is, I don't know what to pick, I have knowledge about SQL(Select * from ) so on and so forth, but the thing is what's the difference between Java DB and MySql?, what should I pick for my project? I am going to create a payroll using Java.

Comment: This might help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4975588/derby-or-mysql-or

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U can find some explanation by searching JavaDB vs MySQL

[Derby or MySQL or...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4975588/derby-or-mysql-or)

for selecting and etc , read the [documentation](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Database-SQL-JDBC/JDBCselect.htm)

```
select.executeQuery("SELECT id, val FROM users");
```

As u see there is slight different in statements , but you already have mysql and know sql statements, MySQL is more complex than javadb and been around for longer period with wider community , which is good when u need help and resources

Comment: I used to use XAMMP, I don't have any experieince with both, I only know SQL statements.

Comment: so u are good to go with mysql , as u see there is slight different in statements , but you already have mysql which is more complex than javadb and been around for longer period with wider community , which is good when u need help and resources

Comment: okay, so how do I start? I am choose MySql, all I know is I need J connector

Comment: If u mean u don't know how to start using mysql JDBC driver ( Connector/J ) , here is some startup tutorial , [Tutorial 1](http://www.vogella.de/articles/MySQLJava/article.html) , [Tutorial 2](http://zetcode.com/databases/mysqljavatutorial/) , u can find couple of them by searching , aslo check this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_lTH3df-yi4

Comment: I am done adding the class path, now how do I know if my connector J is registered?

Comment: o.O i think u need to read one of tutorials to the end , try this http://www.developer.com/java/data/article.php/3417381/Using-JDBC-with-MySQL-Getting-Started.htm

Comment: I don't get it, everything looks correct, I am just trying to convert it from ch to int :|